# rails - how to pass changes back to parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to pass updated paramaters to back to a parent model when saving a series of its children.
For example if a save a bunch of employees to each task  through a project, I need to let the project know the title of some of its tasks have changed, then I need to collect all the titles that changed and process them in the ProjectObserver.  Is this possible?

I realize there might not be a way to make this work the way I'm trying.  If not I'm happy to hear suggestions about how I might be able to get around this.

Here is what I have tried without any success:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employee_tasks
  has_many :tasks, :through => :employee_tasks

  accepts_nested_attributes_For :employee_tasks
  accepts_nested_attributes_For :tasks
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :changed_employees
  has_many :tasks  
end


class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employee_tasks
  has_many :employees, :through => :employee_tasks
  belongs_to :project

  accepts_nested_attributes_For :employee_tasks
end


class EmployeeTask < ActiveRecord::Base
  #this is what I want to accomplish
  before_save do 
    if self.employee_id_changed
      self.task.project.changed_employees ||= []
      self.task.project.changed_employees << self.employee_id_changed
    end
  end
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :employee
end


class ProjectObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe :project
  def after_save(project)
    puts project.changed_employees
    # should print out the changed attributes loaded from EmployeeTask
    #send a single email with all the updated titles (not one email for each change)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use the after_save method described here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html